# PC's, Tablets, IPhones, IPads, Portrait and Landscape text issues

Tags: android, css, iphone, ipad

I am trying to create or find a "rule of thumb" standard for font-sizes in CSS.
The issue I have is that on different devices, different resolutions I find that some font sizes work fine, but then I find issues when in portrait for example.

I have started using **rem** to work out my font sizes and I created a mixing like this:

```
@mixin font-size($sizeValue: 2.4) {
    font-size: ($sizeValue * 10) + px;
    font-size: $sizeValue + rem;
}

@mixin small-size() {
    @include font-size(1.8);

    @include small-width {
        @include font-size(1.8);
    }

    @include large-width {
        @include font-size(1.8);
    }
}
```

The idea was that depending on the resolution of the device I could decrease the font size. But I found that using 2.4 rem actually looked pretty good on all PCs and Laptops. Most tablets in landscape are fine too, but for any in portrait the font is way too small.

I was hoping there was some sort of rule or CSS media query that someone has created that allows you to set a base font size and it will resize using media queries for all devices, but that might be wishful thinking :D

So, does anyone have a solution for this? Or know what I can do to make this easier?

Comment: Take a look at CSS units: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_units.asp Especially `vw` and `vh`...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of work, I found out that anything that uses retina display or similar needs to address everything (margins, padding, width, height, font-size, etc) differently than standard.
Because of the nature of retina, it was pretty straight forward to fix (although it was monotonous). Because I was using Sass (and bootstrap), I simply created a load of mixins like this:

```
@import "../../global/variables";
@import "structure";

@mixin make-font($size) {
    font-size: 1 * $size;

    @include iphone-portrait {
        font-size: 2 * $size;
    }
}

@mixin header-font {
    @include make-font($h1);
}
@mixin lead-font {
    @include make-font($lead);
}
@mixin default-font {
    @include make-font($p);
}
@mixin small-font {
    @include make-font($small);
}
@mixin font-size($size) {
    @include make-font($size);
}
```

as you can see, when I make a font I handle iphone differently (I double the size).
The mixin for the **iphone-portrait** I got from http://stephen.io/mediaqueries/ and adapted for me, so it looks like this:

```
@mixin iphone-portrait {
    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 414px) and (max-device-width : 736px) and (orientation : portrait) {
        @content;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 568px) and (orientation : portrait) {
        @content;
    }

    @media only screen and (min-device-width : 320px) and (max-device-width : 480px) and (orientation : portrait) {
        @content;
    }
}
```

I can keep adding media queries too it, so that should make it easier.
Now this is just for fonts. For other things, I created similar mixins. For example, for the navbar I created this sass:

```
.navbar-default {
    @include make-navbar;
    @include lead-font;
    position: fixed;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    background-color: $white-sky;
    color: $midnight-blue;
    margin: 0;
    border: 0;
    z-index: 1;
    box-shadow: none;
    border-radius: 0;

    @include iphone-portrait {
        @include make-navbar(2);
    }
}
```

and the mixin for the navbar looked like this:

```
@mixin make-navbar($multiplyer: 1) {
    height: $multiplyer * $header-height;
    min-height: $multiplyer * $header-height;

    .navbar-brand {
        margin: 0 $multiplyer * $navbar-brand-margin-left;
        padding: $multiplyer * $navbar-brand-padding;
        height: $multiplyer * $header-height;

        > img {
            max-height: $multiplyer * ($header-height - (2 * $navbar-brand-padding));
        }
    }

    .navbar-header {
        max-height: $multiplyer * $header-height;

        .btn-link {
            margin: 0;
            max-height: $multiplyer * $header-height;
            padding-left: $multiplyer * $button-left-padding;

            .icon {
                margin-top: -$multiplyer * (2 * $button-top-padding);
                height: $multiplyer * ($header-height - (2 * $button-top-padding));

                > svg {
                    height: $multiplyer * ($header-height - (2 * $button-top-padding));
                    width: $multiplyer * ($header-height - (2 * $button-top-padding));
                }
            }
        }


        .navbar-toggle {
            padding: ($multiplyer * $navbar-toggle-padding-top) ($multiplyer * $navbar-toggle-padding-left);

            .fa {
                font-size: $multiplyer * 14px;
            }
        }
    }

    .navbar-nav {
        margin: ($multiplyer * $navbar-nav-toggle-margin-top) auto ($multiplyer * $navbar-nav-toggle-margin-bottom);

        > li > a {
            padding: ($multiplyer * $navbar-nav-list-item-padding-top) ($multiplyer * $navbar-nav-list-item-padding-left);
            line-height: $multiplyer * $navbar-nav-list-item-line-height;
        }

        .open .dropdown-menu > li > a {
            padding: ($multiplyer * $navbar-nav-dropdown-list-item-padding-top) ($multiplyer * $navbar-nav-dropdown-list-item-padding-right) ($multiplyer * $navbar-nav-dropdown-list-item-padding-bottom) ($multiplyer * $navbar-nav-dropdown-list-item-padding-left);
        }
    }
}

@mixin navbar-sub-height($height, $multiplyer: 1) {
    max-height: calc(100vh - #{ $multiplyer * $height });
    max-height: -o-calc(100vh - #{ $multiplyer * $height }); /* opera */
    max-height: -webkit-calc(100vh - #{ $multiplyer * $height }); /* google, safari */
    max-height: -moz-calc(100vh - #{ $multiplyer * $height }); /* firefox */
}
```

As you can see with this, I use a **$multiplyer** which is by default 1. So when I invoke the mixin **@include make-navbar** it uses the normal sizes, but for the iphone media queries I pass 2 like this:

```
$include make-navbar(2)
```

and that doubles everything.

I have tested this out and it works perfectly. Obviously with this approach I can use the mixins anyway I please (so I could pass 1.2 or any value for the $multiplyer).

I hope this helps other people that have a similar issue.